# Webpage Responsive for Mobile view

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a website which must be responsive for mobile phones. I've created it using my desktop.

When I adjust browser windows it's working perfectly  but when I check it on my mobile phone(Microsoft-640), it seems not responsive to the mobile view.

Comment: can you show your web link ?

Comment: have you added the meta tag ?

Comment: You also need `@media` selectors in your CSS if you don't have that.

Answer (score 4):

PLease you can add meta tag viewport for responsive as under:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful to make your website as mobile view by your own.

The Media Queries in CSS3 take this idea and extend it. Rather than looking for a type of device they look at the capability of the device, and you can use them to check for all kinds of things.

For example:

- Width and height (of the browser window)
- device width and height
- orientation – for example is a phone in landscape or portrait mode?
- resolution

**Linking a separate stylesheet using media queries**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css" />
```

The first way to use media queries is to have the alternate section of CSS right inside your single stylesheet. So to target small devices

we can use the following syntax:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

}
```

Example code:

```
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div#wrapper {
        width: 400px;
    }

    div#header {
        background-image: url(media-queries-phone.jpg);
        height: 93px;
        position: relative;
    }

    div#header h1 {
        font-size: 140%;
    }

    #content {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #navigation {
        float:none;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

For some more reference: [1 click me please](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design), [2 click me too](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)